# Trying to deploy my Firebase cloud function that uses an expressjs server to render stuff and it's telling me ESM isn't supported?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, es6-modules

```js
import functions from "firebase-functions";
import createError from 'http-errors'
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser"
import logger from "morgan";
import url from 'url';

const __dirname = path.dirname(new url.URL(import.meta.url).pathname);
const viewsDir = path.join(__dirname, './', 'views/');
const app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(viewsDir));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
// use the qs library for urlencoded strings for structuring urlparams
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
// we're serving the VIEWs already but now we need to serve the static files
// css n stuff
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'public')));

// TECHNICALLY I should move this to a new file, and I will at some point
// when the routes get more complicated.
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/*', (req,res,next)=>{
  res.render('index', {title: 'express '})
});

// use that router, boii
app.use('/', router);

// throw dem errors boiii
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
  next(createError(404));
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // Warn that noise in console cuz life is chaos.
  console.warn(err)
  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

const fapp = functions.https.onRequest(app);

export {fapp, app};
```

I'm exporting fapp and app separately because local server reasons.

1. both my project and my functions package.json use "type": "module"

- The firebase documentation/changelog says that they're using esm as the default for browsers so like... esm is supported. Right? Because it's saying it's not.

2. What's even weirder is that also in my firebase console one of the messages says

- "Detailed stack trace: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /workspace/index.js"
- "require() of /workspace/index.js from /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/loader.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules."
- but... that's not even my code- thats some google stuff.

3. What's EVEN weirder is that my site IS working, but it doesn't work on refresh -- like site.com/ works fine and site.com/subdirectory works fine because it's an spa react app, but if i refresh the page on site.com/subdirectory it doesn't even provide MY 404 page... which is what this cloud function / expressjs app is supposed to fix.

It works fine locally. The express server handles that situation correctly.

So... does anyone know what's up with this or had a similar experience? I really like firebase and I don't wanna change but if I can't use ESM... like... it's 2021.